# How to run load test case from Jmeter for signalR hub api

Tags: jmeter, signalr, load-testing, signalr.client

I have SignalR hubs api , I have to do load testing for those Api from Jmeter tool.

I found there are some socket sampler plugin which I already integrate with jmeter but don't know how to run my signalR service.

Comment: Now I am able to do this help of  http://seleniumparadise.blogspot.in/2015/07/jmeter-web-socket-testing.html

Comment: can you list down steps you followed, i don't see that URL is active anymore.